# Toolbar button click event functionality

Tags: android

I have created settings button in `Toolbar`, now I need to navigate the screen to settings screen, when ever i click the settings button.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<menu xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">;
 <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
android:title="ConfigApp" 
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name" 
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" /> 
</menu>
```

Comment: post button code here

Comment: sounds like you created a menu, if so. Use onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="ConfigApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
</menu>

Comment: Edit the question and post the code there only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onOptionsItemSelected function. This [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu) will help you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_xml, menu);
        return true;
    }

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                //Strar activity here
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should override the `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` methods and take that particular `id` from menuitem and navigate to settings screen.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_xml, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent i = new Intent(yourActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class)
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```